# Pass set of array into MySQL query as parameters

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, implode

what am trying to do here is get data from mysql generated checkboxes. The check  boxes data are in array . So for all the check boxes selected I want to use each as a parameter in a query to get more info from another databastablee.

**Sample Code Below**

```
if (isset($_POST['submitCourseCode'])) { 
     //GET ARRAY FROM DATABASE GENERATED CHECKBOXES                                         
     $aElective =  $_POST['electiveModules'];


    foreach($aElective  as $snode) {                                                    
        echo "$snode <br />";
    }
    //PASSING EACH DATA FROM ARRAY INTO QUERY   
    $Query = "SELECT ID,title,credits 
             FROM module 
             WHERE ID IN('" . implode("', '", $aElective) ."')";

    $Result = mysql_query($Query) 
    or die ("Query failed: " . mysql_error() . " Actual query: " . $Query);

    while ($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)) {

           $id = htmlentities($Row['ID']);
           $title = htmlentities($Row['title']);
           $credits = $Row['credits'];

    echo "<ul>" . $id . " " . $title .  " " . $credits . "</ul>";

    }  
}
var_dump($Query);   
var_dump($Result);  
var_dump($Row);
```

Screenshot of my result
[image]

Am guessing something is happening with my query probably because of the implode function but everything seems fine in my query.Any suggestions on what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trim array elements using `array_map('trim', $aElective)` as:

```
$Query = "SELECT ID,title,credits 
         FROM module 
         WHERE ID IN('" . implode("','", array_map('trim', $aElective)) ."')";
```

Comment: +1, the problem is the extra space, but not quite as @Fluffeh thought. It is here in the $aElective variable.

Comment: @davidethell. I get error when I tried using trim.Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\xtra.php and then the query is empty.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The values need to be trimmed, not the array itself. Do this before you implode: $aElective=array_map('trim',$aElective);

Comment: @davidethell.Thanks so much.My last five hours of trying to figure this out has come to an end.Thanks to U !! Have a great day sir !!

Answer (score 1):

There is  a problem with white spaces before your IDs in IN clause.

Try to add a `str_replace()` call

```
$Query = "SELECT ID,title,credits 
         FROM module 
         WHERE ID IN('" . str_replace(" ", "", implode("', '", $aElective)) ."')";
```

Comment: @wildnove.Thanks for the suggestion. It's working now.Have a great day sir !